# Injecting view from one module into another view in a second module

Tags: wpf, view, prism, viewmodel

I need some help figuring out how to inject a view from one module into another view in a second module, using the Prism library.

I have a CreateOrderView inside my Order module. This view gets injected into a region in the Shell. Now I need to display a PersonCardView inside this CreateOrderView. PersonCardView is a view from my PhoneBookModule.

The view model for PersonCardView takes a Person argument in the constructor which contains the data that the view will display.

In my CreateOrderView, how can I define a "placeholder" to "inject" this PersonCardView? I don't think it would be appropiate to define a region here since it's always this single view, and nothing else.
If the two views was in the same module, I could just include it like this:

```
<PersonCardView DataContext="{Binding PersonCardViewModel}"/>
```

CreateOrderViewModel would of course hold a property called PersonCardViewModel containing the viewmodel for the PersonCardView.

But I can't see how to do it this way unless I create a reference between the two modules and I would like to avoid that.

Any ideas? How have you approached this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, that I can see.

**Your first option** is to **use Regions**. Regions are fine with one control:

```
<ContentControl RegionManager.Region="MyCrossModuleRegion" />
```

This will work fine. No reference between the two is required.

**The second option** is to have the module that consumes the view from the other module (we'll call this the Consuming module) provide a service to the other module producing the view (we'll call this the Producing module) so that the Consuming module can get a factory for those views. An example will hopefully make this clear.

```
//What the Consuming module will expose via the Container
public interface IPersonCardProviderRegistrationService
{
     void RegisterProvider(IPersonCardProvider provider);
}

//What the Producing module will implement and pass to the Consuming module via the above interface
public interface IPersonCardProvider
{
     //If you need some interactivity, this could be an interface,
     //but if it's readonly data and little to no activity, object
     //is a perfectly valid type here
     object GetPersonCardView(long personID);
}
```

In this way, the Consuming module can use the provider to get a view for each person you want to show. The Producing module will just pass the provider to the Consuming module via the RegisterProvider call. The **Producing module would have a ModuleDependency on the Consuming module** in this scenario, but the **only assembly reference necessary would be to a 3rd assembly with those two interfaces** in it (we call this a "Contracts" assembly, but that's not an industry standard term or anything).

Comment: I prefer your first approach.

Comment: @PVitt: it's about taste, more than anything. We've been moving away from RegionManager and focusing on ViewModel-First development. In these situations, the "object" from GetPersonCardView would likely be a ViewModel rather than a view. When it reaches the control tree, it'll be datatemplated with a view using WPF typed DataTemplate feature. I prefer the control I get with this and complete non-reliance on the RegionManager API. Certain things are hard in MVVM when using the RegionManager, like closing a view.